# Log in to my web site using Skype and Whatsapp

Tags: skype, whatsapp

I want to know whether i can create a login to my web site using Skype login and Whatsapp login, like in Google. The users must be able to use skype login details to login to my site. Can this achieved and if yes how? please make me aware about this.
Thanks.

Comment: Well, what does the skype documentation say?

Comment: It has described it's functionalities and not about codings and how to access it.

Comment: If there is no description about such features in their documentation then there certainly is no such feature.

Answer (score 1):

[Whatsapp](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/) doesn't have an external official API (neither do [Skype](http://developer.skype.com/)), so I am afraid not.